# Feasible to repair oven door?

Tags: repair, oven

This weekend, the door of our oven (a gas oven, FWIW) fell apart. The bottom of the outer part of the door was glued to its hinges and somehow lost cohesion. The top is connected to the inner part of the door with screws. Furthermore the inner part has a glas window which fell off a long time ago and just dangled between the parts of the door basically forever (we took over the oven from the previous tenants) but it seems to have been glued to the door in the past.

Basically, it seems to me as if I would be able to fix it. First glue the window to the inner door and then apply glue to the hinges, mount everything with vises and then let the glue harden. Anyway, I'd like to know

- whether it's really as simple as I imagined
- whether there are any caveats I have to be careful about and
- which glue I'd have to use if I decided to do it, normal household-glue would not be suitable I'd guess

(I can add a photo of the door later, maybe this evening.)

Comment: a photo might help. i don't know of a glue that can stand such high temps. it might need to be fastened manually.

Comment: I agree, there is no "glue" that would work on an oven door for very long. Most likely the glue was a cheat-fix used by the previous tenant to make it APPEAR to the landlord as though the oven was not damaged. Once an over door hinge breaks, replacement is the only valid fix.

Comment: @JRaef The door looks as if it was glued ex factory, but I'll have another look at it.

Comment: @dandavis Admittedly I forgot to add the photos yesterday. I'll try to tonight.

Comment: Normally oven doors snap into the hinges so the door can be removed but I have not purchased a new oven since 2000, so they may be different now. Their are high temp epoxies available and the temp adhesive you would need would be based on if it is a self cleaning oven or not 5–600 degree would work for a standard oven, but a self cleaning ? I don’t know how hot they get.